# Adding style using css to ng2-select2 in Angular2

Tags: html, css, angular, jquery-select2

I'm using [ng2-select2](https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2) in my Angular2 project and I want to add some style such as width, height, border-radius, font-weight, font-size, ... but I couldn't manage it.

My Html code is like:

```
<select2 [data]="exampleData"></select2>
```

I also tried adding *class* and *id* to my *select2* element, but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use "width", you can use it with Select2Options class.

In your component just define one object of Select2Options:

```
let options: Select2Options;
```

Set the attribute that you want:

```
this.optionsSelect = {
  placeholder: "Select option...",
  allowClear: true,
  width: "100%"
}
```

In your html, put the [options] input with the name of your option:

```
<select2 [data]="seccion" [cssImport]="true" (valueChanged)="onSeccionChange($event)" [options]="optionsSelect"></select2>
```

With this class you can customize some things, for example: add a placeholder, or allow to keep the select without selection.

In my case , I'm trying to change background-color but I can't find a solution.

Comment: For your background case, you could add in the optionsSelect the attribute dropdownCss with the style you need, e.g.: `dropdownCss: {backgroundColor: 'red'}`

Answer (score 1):

You could try to customize component

```
    @Component({
            selector: "your-component",
            templateUrl: "your-template.component.html",
            styles: [`
                    :host >>> .select2-container {
                                min-width: 1000px;
                    }
            `]
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `width` attribute as mentioned there in the repo description like this

```
<select2 [width]="dynamic_width"></select2>
```

refer from here

https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2#inputs

else you can use `ngStyle` or `ngClass` for dynamic binding to style (PS:- Not Tested)

Comment: Yes, But just width, and it should only be used inline. It doesn't work if you put it to the css file

Comment: no it will not work in css you have to set in HTML itself, also Just width because author of repo mentioned only width there. see the attached link @Kavoos

Comment: @pardeepjain_90, I kinda find a solution! I need to open Chrome console. There you can see that the <select2> element converted to different element and I have to find the right class they use, and then overwrite them. Anyhow it's very annoying!

Comment: great if you find out the solution, yes the only option left is to overright the default class of element.